# At least one element in the source array could not be cast down to the destination array type Multidimensional Array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, office-interop

```
Array.Copy(ws.get_Range("F2", "AL" + (1 + noOfStudents)).Value2, cValuesAll, ws.get_Range("F2", "AL" + (1 + noOfStudents)).Value2.Length);
```

I have this line of code, and I intend to copy the array from `ws.get_Range("F2", "AL" + (1 + noOfStudents)).Value2` to `cValuesAll`. It is throwing an exception `At least one element in the source array could not be cast down to the destination array type`. The arrays are multidimensional.

A similar line of code

```
Array.Copy(ws.get_Range("C2", "AI" + (1 + noOfTeachers)).Value2, aValuesWOSummary, ws.get_Range("C2", "AI" + (1 + noOfTeachers)).Value2.Length);
```

works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

This exception means that the source array contains a value which has a different type from  the type of `cValuesAll` elements. So you have two ways to solve the problem:

**1.** Change cell types for the range F2:AL* in Excel.

**2.** Copy values in `for` cycle, cast a value if possible or report about an invalid cell value to the user.

```
dynamic values = ws.Range["F2", "AL" + (1 + noOfStudents)].Value2;

int firstDimension = values.GetLength(0);
int secondDimension = values.GetLength(1);
double[,] array = new double[firstDimension, secondDimension];

for (int i = 0; i < firstDimension; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < secondDimension; j++)
    {
        object value = values[i + 1, j + 1];

        if (value == null)
        { /* Report about a null value */ }

        if (value is double)
        {
            array[i, j] = (double)value;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out array[i, j]))
            { /* Report about a wrong type */ }
        }
    }
}
```